# sent parameter new Option(this.name, this.id) to function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

problem
i want create function to

```
function set_select_option(select_name, start_value, data, new_option) {
select_name.empty();
select_name.append(new Option(start_value.toString(), 0));
$.each(data, function () {
    select_name.append(new_option) ;
});
};
```

i want use this

```
set_select_option('#select1', 'name0', data1, new Option(this.name, this.id));
```

but this error

```
Option(this.name, this.id)
```

how to fix ?
can be do ?

Comment: You only pass a string as value for `select_name`, not a jQuery object. But aside from that, what does `this` refer to when you call `new Option(this.name, this.id)`? What is the context? You have to provide a better explanation of your problem.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i want use function
set_select_option('#select1', 'name0', data1, new Option(this.name, this.id));
error line
new Option(this.name, this.id)
can be do?

Comment: can be do?
this function set_select_option('#select1', 'name0', data1, new Option(this.name, this.id));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
function set_select_option(select_name, start_value, data) {
    select_name.empty();
    select_name.append(new Option(start_value.toString(), 0));
    $.each(data, function () {
        select_name.append(new Option(this.name, this.id)) ;
    });
};
```

Comment: some data is use Option(this.name, this.value)
data2 = [   { "id": "1", "value": "value1" },
    { "id": "2", "value": "value2" },
    { "id": "3", "value": "value3" }];

Comment: i want create any select option with function set_select_option
and send parameter 
Option(this.name, this.id) or 
Option(this.value, this.id) or
Option(this.text, this.id)